# `print` method for ReferenceClass

Tags: r, reference-class

I have:

> MyClass <- setRefClass("MyClass"
>                          , fields = list(data="numeric"))

Let's initialize an object of `MyClass`:

> OBJ <- MyClass(data=1:4)

... and print it on screen:

> OBJ

```
Reference class object of class "MyClass"
Field "data":
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

I would like to change the way it gets printed so I wrote this method:

> print.MyClass <- function(x) {
>     cat("This is printed representation: ")
>     print(x$data)
>   }

Now this works:

> print(OBJ)

```
This is printed representation: [1] 1 2 3 4
```

this doesn't:

> OBJ

Is there any way to implement my print method with just typing `OBJ`?

I have tried also `show`, or `(OBJ)`, but no love for me.

Comment: You can add a `show` method to your reference class as detailed in `?setRefClass`. `MyClass$methods(show = function(){print("This is printed representation: "); print(data)})` for example.

Comment: Yes it works as requested when I type `OBJ`. Would you like to make this into a regular answer, which I will readily accept and close. Thanks again @jdharrison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `show` method to your reference class as detailed in `?setRefClass`. As an example

```
MyClass <- setRefClass("MyClass" , fields = list(data="numeric"))

MyClass$methods(show = function(){print("This is printed representation: ")
                                  print(data)})

OBJ <- MyClass(data=1:4)

> OBJ
[1] "This is printed representation: "
[1] 1 2 3 4
```